# how jquery ajax fail callback gets triggered if server returns status 200

Tags: php, jquery

When PHP's `E_FATAL` error occurs the server returns the respons with `status 200` and `responseText: "↵Fatal error: error description`. However, the jquery's ajax triggers `fail` callback instead of `done`. Why? For the status 200 it should call done callback.

```
var jQueryDeferred = $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: data
})

jQueryDeferred.done(function (response) {
    if (response.statusCode === 301) {
        window.location.assign(response.data || "/");
        return;
    } else {
        customDeffered.resolve(response);
    }
}).fail(function (response) {
    customDeffered.resolve(response); // THIS CALLBACK IS CALLED
});
```

Comment: you need to provide the code..

Comment: Server did return something, that's why the http status code is 200, but the actual data is not what jQuery expects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*the jquery's ajax triggers fail callback instead of done. Why?*

Because the expected return type *(like json, text, html etc.)* is not that which is required.

consider this example:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "your url",
    type : "post",
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(response){
       console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error){
       alert(error.responseText);
    }
});
```

if you return some json object from the specified url then you will get into the success block and that would print the response in the browser's console.

But if there is some error and if it is returning string instead of json then it would go into the error block.

Comment: How does jquery knows that _expected return type (like json, text, html etc.) is not that which is required._ ? Does it call parseJSON() function which determines that?

Comment: Yes internally jQuery library does that for you, that's why we need to have dataType in out ajax codes. because dataType determines what type of data in response is.

Comment: Thanks! So I also runs validation of the datatype I specified, correct? If I specify datatype `html`, it will parse and validation HTML, correct?

Comment: Yes, as far as response contains html.

Comment: Got you, thanks! What happens if I don't specify the type of the expected response?

Answer (score 4):

The fail handler is called because you are specifying the response content type as JSON. A PHP fatal error can not be parsed as JSON and so jQuery triggers the fail handler.

```
var jQueryDeferred = $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json", // <-- here
    data: data
})
```

If you remove the JSON dataType, the success handler will be called instead, but jQuery will not automatically parse the JSON, so you'll have to do it manually.